# Regarding Keyerror while using Python json module

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

would be helped if the mistake is pointed. 
Here Iam trying to create a code for displaying the name of the city state and country by taking Pincode as input, Thanks in advance

```
    import urllib, json
from urllib.request import urlopen
from tkinter import *
global pincode
root=Tk()
frame=Frame(root,width=250,height=250)
frame.grid()
class cal:

    def __init__(self):
        self.string=StringVar()
        entry=Entry(frame,textvariable=self.string)
        entry.grid(row=1,column=2,columnspan=6)
        but=Button(root,text="submit",command=self.pin)
        but.grid()
    def pin(self):
        pincode=self.string.get()

        url = "https://www.whizapi.com/api/v2/util/ui/in/indian-city-by-postal-code?pin="+pincode+"&project-app-key=fnb1agfepp41y49jz6a39upx"
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        data = json.loads(response.read().decode('utf8'))
        fi=open("neme.txt","w")
        fi.write(str(data))        
        state=data['State']
        city=data['City']
        area=data['area']
        name=Label(frame,text="State:"+state+"City:"+city+"area:"+area)
        name.grid(row=3,column=0)







    cal()

    mainloop()
```

error being

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1541, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/yuvi/Documents/LiClipse Workspace/GUI/src/Pn_code.py", line  24, in pin
    state=data['State']
KeyError: 'State'
```

Comment: Why don't you `print(data)` to see whether that key exists? Maybe is has a different spelling (case matters) or you are getting an error response? Also, what is `pincode`?

Comment: You would be knowing ZIP code i assume which is used as pincode

Answer (score 2):

Ok. Error tells you that you don't have key named "State" in you dict under `data` variable. So maybe there isn't also in incomming json.

If in response you get:

```
{"ResponseCode":0,"ResponseMessage":"OK","ResponseDateTime":‌​"9/3/2016 2:41:25 PM GMT","Data":[{"Pincode":"560103","Address":"nagar","City":"B‌​analore","State":"na‌​taka","Country":"Ind‌​ia"}]}
```

then you cannot get "State" by using:

```
data["State"]
```

you have to do it using:

```
data["Data"][0]["State"]
```

and the rest:

```
data["Data"][0]["City"]
data["Data"][0]["Country"]
```

Why in this way? Because you have to get nested keys, first key is `"Data"`, using `data["Data"]` you recieve a list, and because it's one element list, you have to get first item of the list: `data["Data"][0]`. And at the end under `data["Data"][0]` you get dict of keys where you can find State, City, Country.

Comment: You can check the link if it helps , there is a keyword State

Comment: This is what I get: ``{"ResponseCode":20,"ResponseMessage":"PIN Code Does Not Exist","ResponseDateTime":"9/3/2016 2:41:36 PM GMT","Data":[]}``

Comment: {"ResponseCode":0,"ResponseMessage":"OK","ResponseDateTime":"9/3/2016 2:41:25 PM GMT","Data":[{"Pincode":"560103","Address":"nagar","City":"Banalore","State":"nataka","Country":"India"}]}

Comment: The thing is , it is only for a single country, 400008 can be entered if it helps

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1541, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/yuvi/Documents/LiClipse Workspace/GUI/src/Pn_code.py", line 27, in pin
    city=data["Data"][1]["city"]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @Yuva  Edited for the rest of variables.

Comment: yup i did for the rest

Comment: @Yuva I've explained why.